# Access ASP.NET website's Database using Android?

Tags: android

I've a website which has users accounts profiles, ..etc .
I would like to CRUD that database using my android application, how can I do that ?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how to do it, but you can use KSOAP2 library in your application to communicate with your server. I guess this link might help: [KSOAP2-Android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse?tm=2)
This example might also help to overcome the issue: [Android system using ksoap2-android client library operation asp.net WebService](http://unknownerror.net/2011-05/android-system-using-ksoap2-android-client-library-operation-asp-net-webservice-32130)

Comment: what if the website is a web application and not a web service

Comment: Try if this can support the requirement: [WebApp.Net](http://webapp-net.com/). I don't know anything about this one, though.